# A set as a graph of a function

Tags: proof-writing, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

The unit sphere $n$ dimensional is the set $$\mathbb{S}^n=\bigg\{(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_{n+1})\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\;|\;\big(x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_{n+1}^2\big)^{1/2}=1\bigg\}.$$
For all $i=1,\dots, n+1$ denote with $U_i^+$ the subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ so defined $$U_i^+=\bigg\{\big(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_{n+1}\big)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\;|\; x_i>0\big)\bigg\}.$$

We consider the continous function $f\colon\mathbb{B}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ so defined $u\mapsto\sqrt{1-\lvert u\rvert^2}$. Then for all $i=1,\dots, n+1$, $U_i^+\cap \mathbb{S}^n$ is the graph of the function  $$x_i=f(x_1, x_2,\dots, x_{i-1},x_{i+i},\dots, x_{n+1}).$$

> Let's prove explicitly what has just been said.

In symbols, pointing with $\hat{x}=(x_1,\dots, x_{i-1}, x_{i+1},\dots, x_{n+1})$, for all $i=1,\dots, n+1$ we have
$$U_i^+\cap \mathbb{S}^n=\bigg\{x=(\hat{x}, x_i)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}\;|\; \hat{x}\in\mathbb{B}^n,x_i=f(\hat{x})\bigg\}.$$
Indeed, if $x\in U_i^+\cap \mathbb{S}^n$, then $x_i>0$ and $\lvert x \rvert =1$ On $U_i^+$ can resolve the equation $\lvert x \rvert=1$ respect to $x_i$ then we have $$x_i=\sqrt{1-(x_1)^2- \cdots -(x_{i-1})^2-(x_{i+1})^2- \cdots - (x_{n+1})^2}.$$ If we consider the vector $\hat{x}=(x_1, x_2,\dots, x_{i+1}, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_{n+1})$ we have $\lvert \hat{x} \rvert <1$, then $\hat{x}\in\mathbb{B}^n$, therefore $x=(\hat{x}, x_i)\in U_i^+\cap\mathbb{S}^n$.
Vice versa, if $x=(\hat{x}, x_i)\in U_i^+\cap \mathbb{S}^n$, then $\hat{x}\in\mathbb{B}^n$ and $x_i=\sqrt{1-\lvert \hat{x} \rvert}>0$, moreover $\lvert x \rvert=1$, therefore $x\in\mathbb{S}^n$

> **Question.** Is my reasoning formally correct?

Comment: Notice that when $|\hat x|^2 = 1$, $f(\hat x) = 0$. Shouldn't you require in the definition of $U_i^{+}$ that $x_i\geqslant 0$, rather than merely $>0$?

Comment: @FimpellizieriThanks for your comment. Yes, $U_i^+$ for $i=1,\dots, n+1$ are the open sets of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ as defined in the text.

Comment: What I mean is that the graph of

$$x_i=f(x_1, x_2,\dots, x_{i-1},x_{i+i},\dots, x_{n+1})$$

contains points with $x_i = 0$, namely those in the intersection of the hyperplane $x_i=0$ with $\Bbb S^n$. These points, however, do not lie in $U_i^+ \cap \Bbb S^n$.

Comment: @Fimpellizierimaybe my writing is ambiguous, sorry, that's why I asked if it was formally correct, now I'll explain better: if $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ is $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, I assumed that this vector can be written as a vector of $\mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}$ as for example $x=((x_2,x_3), x_1)$. Then the vector $\hat{x}$ is the vector to which the i-th component has been removed, and $x_i$ is precisely this component.

Comment: @Fimpellizierimy book just says it's easy to check that $U_i^+\cap\mathbb{S}^n$ is the graph of the function $x_i=f(x_1,\dots,\hat{x_i},\dots, x_{n+1})$ where the hat indicates that $x_i$ is omitted. f my procedure is not formally correct, could you suggest a correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your book uses strange notation, and is possibly wrong.
The graph $\Gamma_f$ of $f: A \longrightarrow B$ is defined as the subset of $A \times B$ given by $\Gamma_f = \{(a,b) \in A\times B\mid b = f(a)\}$.

The equation $x_i = f(x_1,x_2,\dots,\hat{x_i},\dots,x_n, x_{n+1})$ is not a function and hence does not have a graph, but it *implicitly* defines a subset $S_i$ of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ via

$$S_i = \left\{(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})\in\Bbb R^{n+1}\,\middle|\, x_i = f(x_1,x_2,\dots,\hat{x_i},\dots,x_n, x_{n+1})\right\}.$$

Moreover, as I pointed out in the comments, the book appears to be wrong.
There are points in $S_i$ whose $i$-th coordinates is $0$.
Indeed, if $H_i\subset R^{n+1}$ is the hyperplane $\left\{(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})\in\Bbb R^{n+1}\,\middle|\, x_i =0\right\}$, then any $p\in H_i \cap \Bbb S^n$ satisfies the equation $x_i = f(x_1,x_2,\dots,\hat{x_i},\dots,x_n, x_{n+1})$ and hence lies in $S_i$.
No such $p$ however lies in $U_i^+$, so the claim made by the book cannot be right.

Comment: @Fimpellizierithanks for your detailed answer. It seems strange to me that the example is completely wrong on the book. That book is Introduction to smooth manifolds, by Lee. Perhaps the author intends to say something else. Certainly this being the case as you explained to me, the example is wrong.